# Show controls in php/mysql on hover

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, hover

I have below radio button on my web,

```
<input id='element_1_1' name='element_1' class='element radio' type='radio' value='1' />
<label class='choice' for='element_1_1'>2!</label>
<input id='element_1_2' name='element_1' class='element radio' type='radio' value='2' />
<label class='choice' for='element_1_2'> 1 </label>
```

When user is between the option, I want a check box to appear or a radio button using which user can select 1.5, the radio button should not appear usually only on hover, any ideas how to do it. I am guessing javascript is involved but all results on SO have jQuery in them which I have no idea about

Comment: You are going to want to learn some `AJAX`. For most people, it is not fruitful nowadays to write AJAX on your own, so I would recommend JQuery. PHP is a server-side language - that is, by the time the user loads the page (in most cases), all of PHP's work is merely finished. http://jquery.com/

Comment: @RageD: Wait wut? Why does he need `AJAX` functionality? If I understand OP correctly he just wants to display an extra radio button on hover. Correct me if wrong OP

Comment: I see, sorry about that, I read it too quickly. If that's the case, simple HTML div/css (show/hide) could work.

Comment: @RageD "HTML div/css (show/hide)" u r suggesting a css?

Comment: @jaminator: Yes, CSS should be able to work properly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168172/radio-button-show-hover-between-two-radio-button-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code implemented here http://jsfiddle.net/xFqf5/2/
By 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/445303/nick

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by adding `display: none` to the styling of the individual radio button and then manipulating it with jQuery's `.hover()` and `.css()` functions.

Little example:

Button:

```
<input id='radioButton' name='radioButton' style='display: none' type='radio' value='1' />
<label class='choice' for='radioButton'>1</label>
```

jQuery stuff:

```
$('#radioButton').hover(function() {
  // blah - show
  $('#radioButton').css('display', 'block')
}, function() {
  // blah - hide
  $('#radioButton').css('display', 'none')
});
```