# Radio button show hover between two radio button using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i have following radio button:

```
<input id='element_1_1' name='element_1' class='element radio' type='radio' value='1' />
<label class='choice' for='element_1_1'>1</label> <br>
<input id='element_1_2' name='element_1' class='element radio' type='radio' value='2' />
<label class='choice' for='element_1_2'>2</label>
```

now when user hovers over the space between two radio buttons i want another radio button to fade in 1.5, the if user moves out it should fade out, there is line break between 2 radio button so dont need the form to slide down. but the 1.5 radio button should appear after a tab not in the same left margin as 1 & 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.fadeToggle()` on your 1.5 elements.

Keep in mind that if the user moves in and out of the elements really quickly, it will have an annoying effect; to combat this, check out this thread: [Jquery Image Fade Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073368/jquery-image-fade-out/7073464#7073464)